# Save a photo and video in a database by viewing

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have a program with login and logout.
I have an exercise class, I have a create view that allows me to create exercises that are composed by name, photo, video.
I fill the form in View Create and when I click create this error appears to me

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
WebApplication1.Controllers.ExerciciosGinasiosController.Create(ExerciciosGinasio exerciciosGinasio, IFormFile fotografia, IFormFile video) in ExerciciosGinasiosController.cs

            string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);
```

In the exercise class I have

```
 [Table("Exercicios_Ginasio")]
    public partial class ExerciciosGinasio
    {
        public ExerciciosGinasio()
        {
            Inclui = new HashSet<Inclui>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDExercicios_Ginasio")]
        public int IdexerciciosGinasio { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("texto_descritivo")]
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string TextoDescritivo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("foto")]

        public string Foto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("video")]

        public string Video { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("IdexerciciosGinasioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Inclui> Inclui { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the controller belonging to the Exercises class (ExercisesController) I have this method in order to create a new exercise

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdexerciciosGinasio,Nome,TextoDescritivo,Foto,Video")] ExerciciosGinasio exerciciosGinasio, IFormFile fotografia,IFormFile video)
        {
            string caminho = Path.Combine(_hostEnviroment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot\\Exercicios");

            string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);
            string caminho_completo = Path.Combine(caminho, nome_ficheiro);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(caminho_completo, FileMode.Create);
            fotografia.CopyTo(fs);
            exerciciosGinasio.Foto = caminho_completo;
            fs.Close();




            string caminho2 = Path.Combine(_hostEnviroment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot\\Exercicios");

            string nome_ficheiro2 = Path.GetFileName(video.FileName);
            string caminho_completo2 = Path.Combine(caminho2, nome_ficheiro2);

            FileStream _fs = new FileStream(caminho_completo2, FileMode.Create);
            video.CopyTo(_fs);
            exerciciosGinasio.Video = caminho_completo2;
            _fs.Close();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _context.Add(exerciciosGinasio);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(exerciciosGinasio);
        }
```

And in the view of this method I have

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ExerciciosGinasio

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}


<h4>Criar Exercicio</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nome" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nome" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TextoDescritivo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TextoDescritivo" type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TextoDescritivo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Foto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Foto" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".png, .jpg, .bmp" value="" />
                @*<span asp-validation-for="Foto" class="text-danger"></span>*@

                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="fotografia" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Video" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Video" type="file" class="form-control" />
                    @*<span asp-validation-for="Video" class="text-danger"></span>*@
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="video" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Voltar</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Does anyone know what may be causing this error? And how can I solve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);

In your View page, we can find you are using hidden field(s) with default value 0 for `fotografia` and `video`, but your **Create** action expects file via `IFormFile` object, if you debug your code, you would find `fotografia` is **null**, which would casue exception while you read **FileName** property of `fotografia`.

To fix it, you can modify the code like below.

*Inputs of Photo and Video*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Foto" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="fotografia" accept=".png, .jpg, .bmp" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Foto" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Video" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="file" name="fvideo" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Video" value="0" />
</div>
```

*Controller Action*

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([Bind("IdexerciciosGinasio,Nome,TextoDescritivo,Foto,Video")] ExerciciosGinasio exerciciosGinasio, 
    IFormFile fotografia, 
    IFormFile fvideo)
{
    string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);

    //code logic here

        
    return View(exerciciosGinasio);
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]